# Validation Errors for HTML 5

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility, w3c-validation, wai-aria

[image: Validation errors]

I'm getting a crazy set of errors. I'm using Bootstrap code and have not edited it. So why is this showing an error?

> A `link` element with a `sizes` attribute must have a `rel` attribute that contains the value `icon` or the value `apple-touch-icon`.

…

> Bad value `banner` for attribute `role` on element `nav`.

To see the same thing live, go to 
https://validator.w3.org/nu and enter: www.iqtests4kids.com/

Answer (score 6):

Maintainer of the W3C HTML checker (validator) here. The `rel=apple-touch-icon-precomposed` error is because I recently updated the checker to conform to [HTML spec requirements for `sizes`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-link-element:attr-link-sizes-2):

> The `sizes` attribute is used with the `icon` link type. The attribute must not be specified on `link` elements that do not have a `rel` attribute that specifies the `icon` keyword or the `apple-touch-icon` keyword.

About the error for `role=banner` on `nav`, that’s because the checker conforms to requirements in the ARIA in HTML spec that [`nav` must not have any role other than `navigation`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#rules-wd).

But note that the ARIA in HTML spec [also states the following requirement](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#rules-wd):

> Web developers should not set the ARIA `role` and `aria-*` attributes to values that match the implicit ARIA semantics defined in the table.

And requirements in “the table” cited state that [the implicit semantics of `nav` are `navigation`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#nav).

Therefore, if you use `role=navigation` with `nav`, the checker will emit a warning.

So bottom line is, per the ARIA in HTML requirements, `nav` should never have an explicit `role`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the Validator is happier with:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon".....
```

instead of

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"......
```

And for the other error, you can make the Validator happy by altering the offending `role="banner"` setting to `"role=navigation"`:

```
<nav id="main-menu" ..... role="navigation">
```

either leaving it in and living with the resulting 'Warning' or omit the value completely (the best solution) and the Validator will be happy :)

Comment: "the W3C has explicitly advised" — Please read the top of the page you quoted: **does not necessarily represent consensus and it may have incorrect information or information that is not supported by other Working Group participants, WAI, or W3C**

Comment: "As for Bootstrap: I am not familiar with this application" — It isn't an application. It is a template with some associated CSS and JS.

Comment: "it creates HTML and CSS either automatically or semi-automatically." — It doesn't.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, I have pruned the incorrect assertions from my answer...